# Blender 2.8 is rendering in eevee when cycles is selected

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have a rigid body simulation that I rendered in eevee and I made an MP4 from it. I want to render the same thing in cycles but every time I try to render it renders in eevee even though cycles is the rendering engine selected. Does anyone have a possible fix?
I've already tried closing and reopening the project and the problem still persists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best to attach your .blend file. Are you using multiple View Layers?

Comment: How do I attach the .blend file? And I'm not using multiple View Layers

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Thanks, .blend file is now uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your attach Blend file, I see nothing rendering both for Eevee or Cycles ((2.80 2019-07-29). Not sure what the problem is. In either case, I was able to workaround the problem by selecting ALL objects in the first scene, creating a new, empty scene and pasting all the copied objects in the second scene. After that, it renders fine in both Eevee and Cycles.

Comment: Ok, I'll see if that works for me.

Comment: As much as I'd love to know the issue, I'm glad this worked, thanks!